# Tracking a clients QR Codes - Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, qr-code, utm

We would like to track clicks on QR codes on behalf of a client - they have their own analytics account - but we would like to track the clicks to determine whether a QR code is required on future campaigns.

We initially thought that we would provide a url to a page on our server which would track the click and re-direct to the relevant link - but we have also read about urchin tracking modules and wondered whether these could be used in this scenario instead as a less labour intensive method?  Does anyone have any experience with this - if so could you advise on best practice?

Can anybody

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on web masters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You can track that by using a relatively new feature in Google Analytics: the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/). It allows you to send data straight to GA via HTTP requests.